# Sequelize MySql, get Questions and include Answers submitted by given user Id

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am using Sequelize with Mysql, in my Node.js application. I have designed a question and answer module where a user can answer a question and is stored in Question_Answers table.
Question_Answers table has the question_id, answer, and user_id (the one who submitted the answer).
I am trying to fetch all the Question including the answers by user_id.

```
data = await Questions.findAll({
        where: {
          status: 1,
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: Question_Answers,
            where: { user_id : 1 },
            attributes: [
              'id',
              'question_id',
              'answer',
              'user_id',
            ],
            as: 'answers',
          },
        ],
      });
```

Here if no answers is submitted by the user, even the question is not returned, but what I want is I still want to get question but answers can be empty object/list.

If I remove the where condition I will get all the answers, which is not posted even by that user_id.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works, when required = false is provided alongside the where condition.

```
data = await Questions.findAll({
    where: {
      status: 1,
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: Question_Answers,
        where: { user_id : 1 },
        attributes: [
          'id',
          'question_id',
          'answer',
          'user_id',
        ],
        required: false,
        as: 'answers',
      },
    ],
  });
```